# CloudSearch performance with frequent updates of small batches

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I have a use case where I need to upload small document batches (typical 1 to 10 documents of 1KB each) to CloudSearch. Every 2 or 3 seconds a new batch is uploaded. The [CloudSearch docs for bulk uploads](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/uploading-data.html#bulk-uploads) say:

> Make sure your batches are as close to the 5 MB limit as possible. Uploading a larger amount of smaller batches slows down the upload and indexing process.

It's ok if there is a 30 seconds delay before the documents show up in search results. Will my implementation work well as my document count is increasing, let's say to 500.000 docs?

Comment: Are you using SQS to queue your batch ? implementing SQS should help you build your batch

Comment: I have a DynamoDBStream that triggers a Lambda. This Lambda uploads the new DynamoDB data to CloudSearch. I have no control over the DynamoDBStream polling frequency. I think your suggestion could help to gain control over the batches by decoupling the DynamoDBStream and the CloudSearch upload with a queue. I was not familiar with SQS yet, thanks, I will take a look at it. I'm still interested though if my use case could work as described above.

Comment: Did it work out for you in the end? What kind of performance were you able to achieve with this setup? I'm looking to use DynamoDB streams as well, with even smaller batches - maybe once every few sec. ~1-3 sec SLA would be perferct. Thanks

Comment: I do not have exact data available, but I can say that documents are searchable within a few seconds.

Comment: @PeterFennema What frequency are uploading them at and what is your instance size?  Cloudsearch docs says uploadDocs should be called once in 10 seconds. Are you able to call it more frequently than that without running into throttling issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing time should be well under your 30 second SLA even with 500k docs, regardless of how or whether you batch your submissions.

I say this based on my own testing with an index of 300k docs and 38 index fields on an m1.small instance type, where it takes less than 3 seconds for a document to be searchable. There are a lot of variables that could affect your own situation, such as how many index fields you have, your instance size, etc, but I think my setup reflects the unfavorable conditions (m1.small instance with complex indexing schema) and is still an order of magnitude faster than your SLA. It's anecdotal evidence of course, but you should be fine.

Comment: I use m1.small too, I will have about 10 index fields. So your testing experience gives me sufficient confidence that my solution will work well.